# NSData to NSString conversion

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdata

I found this method to convert an NSData to an NSString object.

```
NSData *data = //some data
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", data];
```

How will the data be decoded? Is `NSUTF8StringEncoding` applied?

Thank you!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is **not** the recommended approach.  Instead use:

```
NSString *newString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

This will ensure you have a specified encoding for the data.

Comment: Wrong!!  NSData.description returns a hex dump.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, the `stringWithFormat:` method will send `NSData` object the `description` message, get the result, and use that for the content of the newly created string. Essentially, the result is identical to

```
NSString *string = [data description];
```

According to [`NSData`'s documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html), `description` returns

> An NSString object that contains a hexadecimal representation of the receiver’s contents in NSData property list format.

Comment: Right.  And I vaguely recall that `description` for NSData is a hex dump.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, I was looking for that piece of documentation to copy-paste a quote :)

Comment: I just tested it on the hardware -- hex dump.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should be using `NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding:SomeFormOfEncoding];`

You can view the method details [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

The forms of encoding can be seen [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSStringEncoding).